# Wait For Image To Be Loaded Before Displayed

Tags: css, image, xhtml

Is there a simple HTML/XHTML/CSS Code for displaying an image after it is done fully loading?

The reason being is because I have a rather large background image and header image (Bytes-Wise) and want to wait for the image to be fully loaded before it is displayed in the browser.

I believe watching the image load bit-by-bit is a bit unattractive.

Thank you!
Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `visibility:hidden` and change it to `visibility:visible` on the image's onload event handler.

**edit: example**

In your HTML, have:

```
<img onload="imgLoad(this)" style="visibility:hidden" ... />
```

In your script, have:

```
function imgLoad(img) {
    img.style.visibility='visible';
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? Is that JavaScript? I am confused! lol :) Thank you.

Comment: @AaronBrewer that is indeed JS, but I would recommend you bind the click event via JS directly and not modify your HTML.

Comment: So for example...

<head>
<script>
function imgLoad(img) {
    img.style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img onload="imgLoad("Img-Source")" style="visibility:hidden" ... />
</body>

?

Thank you.

Comment: @JohnP, so how would I come across doing this?